# The expression сыграть статью

Tags: выражения

In these [verses](https://www.b-pasternak.ru/vse-stixotvoreniya/vstuplenie) by Boris Pasternak:

> На свете былей непочатый край,
> Ничем не замечательных - тем боле.
> Не лез бы я и с этой, не сыграй
> Статьи о ней своей особой роли.

I don't understand the expression сыграть статью: I would translate it literally as "to play an (newspaper) article", which doesn't make much sense to me. I'd be okay with "не прочти статьи" instead of "не сыграй статьи" - does сыграть have the same meaning as прочесть?

Comment: The expression here is not "сыграть статью" but "сыграть роль", which is equivalent to English "play a role".

Comment: @il--ya Quassnoi already very well answered my question: I thought Статьи was in the accusative while it is in the nominative.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This one is tricky indeed, but unlike some other Pasternak's lyrics, it makes perfect sense.

*Не лез бы я и с этой (былью), не сыграй статьи о ней своей особой роли* means "I wouldn't have been pushing this one (account) had the articles about it not played their special role"

Just to clarify, *статьи* is in the nominative and *роли* is in the genitive in this sentence.

1. Verbs in what formally is the second-person singular imperative can convey the subjunctive mood in Russian:

   > - Не вернись деньги в банк, несчастную женщину оштрафовали бы на пропавшую сумму. *[Происшествия (1997) // «Столица», 29.07.1997]* // Had the money not returned to the bank, the poor woman would have been fined the missing amount.
   > - Что было бы с нами, установи мы палатку под защитой леса? *[Виктор Шереметьев. Путешествие в «забытый край» // «Дальний Восток», 2019]* // What would have happened to us had we set up the tent under the shelter of the forest?
2. Direct objects to verbs can accept both the genitive and the accusative when the verb is negated: *не пить воду/воды, не есть мясо/мяса, не играть роль/роли*. This distinction is meaningful and there is [a whole chapter](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/66.htm#%D0%B7_04) about it in Rosenthal. This particular case is covered by §201.1.5:

   > Родительный падеж, имеющий в рассматриваемой конструкции значение подчеркнутого отрицания, обычно употребляется в следующих случаях:
   >
   > … при выражении дополнения отвлеченными существительными: *не дает оснований, не обнаруживает понимания, не теряет надежды, не скрывает радости, не осуществляет контроля, не упускает случая, не делает уступок*. Например: *Здесь шума не любят (Горький); Веселья я не ищу (В. Кетлинская); Утро не принесло ясности (Леонов)*